# Are polarization-entangled photons correlated spatially?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics

Are polarization-entangled photons correlated spatially?

That is, if I took a pair of entangled photons and looked at their spatial modes with two cameras (one for each photon), would I expect to see correlations between their spatial modes? Does this change depending on if the photons are generated colinearly or not colinearly?

My intuition would be that there is a sort of "momentum conservation" which forces the photons to be anticoorelated in space. Here's a drawing for a visualization:

[image]
EDIT: obviously a polarization entangled state can be written on it's own without having any other criteria. That is, you can write something like $|H\rangle|H\rangle+|V\rangle|V\rangle$ theoretically, which doesn't have spatial mode entanglement, but I'm interested in real-life cases.

Comment: Anticorrelation does not imply entanglement.

Comment: I'm asking for the reverse. Does polarization-entanglement (for real photons generated with a chi2 nonlinearity with a pump of a gaussian spatial mode) imply that the individual spatial modes of the two photons will be anti-correlated?

Comment: Anti-correlated or entangled? Otherwise, I can always redirect entangled photons through a mirror to anti-correlate them.

Comment: I used "anti-correlated" to try to make it more clear why it might be the case, but sure I think it's fine to rephrase to something more technical: "Is there typically CV spatial-mode entanglement for realistic experiments that generate polarization-entangled photons. (such as SPDC from a nonlinear crystal)"

Comment: I'm not sure about your criterion for "real-life cases", but I have the feeling that you will reject any example without spatial mode entanglement.  For the very least, you can decrease the spatial mode entanglement even in PDC as much as you want by choosing a very small angle from which you use the photons.  Or send them through some fiber which scrambles the spatial degree of freedom. Or create them inside a cavity where emission in a given spatial mode is very much enhanced.  But of course, as long as there is some uncertainty in the spatial degrees of freedom,...

Comment: ... you expect them to be entangled, unless there is some environment which will cause the state to be mixed rather than entangled.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, your examples are what I'm looking for.

Comment: "For the very least, you can decrease the spatial mode entanglement even in PDC as much as you want by choosing a very small angle from which you use the photons." Small angle near the center so the relative angle change due to "momentum conservation" is close to zero?
"Or send them through some fiber which scrambles the spatial degree of freedom." 
I'm particularly interested in this answer...Why would the fiber scramble this information? (maybe it flips it or changes the entanglement a bit, but why would it cause it to become uncorrelated?)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, "Or create them inside a cavity where emission in a given spatial mode is very much enhanced. But of course, as long as there is some uncertainty in the spatial degrees of freedom"  That's an interesting point, but I would expect that since you need an even number of mirrors, the amount that the spatial mode "flips" will be even, and the spatial "cross-correlation" will always constructively interfere. ...maybe that intution is wrong?

Comment: I'd say the general rule is: If it is not forbidden by the laws of physics, there is a way to create it (though it might be challenging).  And, as you acknowledge, it *is* possible to create such a state. So there is a more or less realistic way to create a more or less reasonable approximation to such a state.